# Creating table with attributes and style of legend using QGIS composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, table

Is it possible to create a table in QGIS composer in which I can display organized additional information about items from one layer as well as the symbol of the categorized symbology?

For example:
Layer1

| species | regional redlist-state | nationwide rl-state | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bird1 | 1 | 2 | .. |
| bird2 | 3 | * | .. |

The symbols for Layer1 are categorized by the species-column.

I know the attribute table, which is almost perfect. The problem is that I didn't found a solution to show the symbol of the categorized symbols for the layer as well.

It would be nice if the symbol would be shown in the first column. I'm pretty sure that there might be a way, but don't know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is a way to do this using just a table, probably not. What you could do is this workaround.

1) Add additional empty column to the shapefile and in the print composer display the attribute table, and move the empty column to the left, like this:

[image]

2) Add legend, change the name of each symbol to space (' '). Depending if you have a multiple shapefiles or one shapefile with multiple symbols, you might need to mark your group shapefile as "hidden". Should look like this: 
[image]

3) Align the two by playing with row height in attribute table and symbol spacing in the legend. I know it's kind of a lot of hassle for a small thing, but it works!

[image]

Comment: alright, yeah of course this workaround might work for a small set of attributes, but in my situation I have quite a lot attributes. So Iguess this looks like a feature request if it's not possible yet?